# methods overriding and overloading

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

can i overload or override methods just by using different return value ? is virtual matter in thie case ?

for example :

```
class A{

  virtual int Foo(); // is this scenario possible with/without the keyword virtual
}

class B : public A {
   virtual double Foo();
}

A* Base = new B();
int i = Base->Foo(); // will this just convert double to int ?
```

and regarding overloading :

```
class A{

  virtual int Foo(); 
  virtual float Foo(); // is this possible ?

  int Goo();
  float Goo(); // or maybe this ?
}

Class B{
    double Foo();
}
```

thanks

Comment: use the 1/0 button to format code

Answer (score 8):

The return type of a function is not part of its signature, thus it can't be overloaded.

Comment: This by definition of the language.

Answer (score 4):

The return value is not part of the function signature, how would the compiler now which version to chose?

If you remove `virtual` from `Foo` in your first example it will work and call `Base::Foo`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot do that.

What you can do in an overriden method is to return a pointer/reference to a type which is a descendant of the type returned by parent's method.

Example:

```
struct VA {}
struct VB : struct VA {}

class A
{
public:
    virtual VA * get();
}

class B
{
public:
    virtual VB * get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloading with only change in the return value is not possible.

consider this:

```
Base->Foo();
```

called without any return value assigning then compiler cannot deduce which method to invoke.

`virtual` keyword is used for creating `VTable` and thereby proving dynamic polymorphism. It has no impact on overloading methods.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is not part of the signature, unfortunetly, so no.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are some similar thing you can do however e.g. templatize the return value (possibly with specializations) and specify the template type when calling e.g.

```
template<T>
T Foo()
{
  return 0;
}

template<>
double Foo<double>()
{
  return 3.14;
}

int i = Foo<int>(); // 0
double d = Foo<double>(); //3.14
```

Comment: actaully you may have to make them functors to do this properly

Answer (score 1):

As far as overriding is concern it is pertaining to class hirearchy and it possible to achieve runtime polymorhism.

```
class Abstract
{
   public :  
   virtual Abstract* Clone() const = 0;
};

class Concrete1 : public Abstract  
{
   public :  
   Concrete1* Clone() const { return new Concrete1(*this); }
};

class Concrete2 : public Abstract  
{
   public :  
   Concrete2* Clone() const {  return new Concrete2(*this); }
};
```

Overloading across scopes is not possible as per C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a "overloaded method only differs in return type" type of error if you're using VC++. This is because method/function signatures don't incorporate the return type. I'm guessing it's because of the ambiguity it can cause if the return value isn't being assigned to anything. e.g

int iMyvar = object.method(); // obvious what type should be returned

Contrast with:-

object.method(); // which overload would the compiler call if return type was part of signature? Ambiguos.